# Cross-referencing across folders

Tags: cross-referencing, xr

I have multiple documents which require cross-referencing from one another (I am the author of all of them). Each document lies in a separate folder.

As an example, everything lives in a directory named "main-folder". Within this directory, I have two directories: "folder-1" and "folder-2". Within each directory (folder-1 and folder-2) lives a TeX document, say file-1.tex is in folder-1 and file-2.tex is in folder-2.

I am using the xr package, and when two TeX documents needing cross-referencing are within the same directory (say, both in folder-1), I enter the following two lines in the preamble of file-1.tex:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[someprefix-]{file-2}
```

and this allows me to cross-reference labels from file-2.tex in file-1.tex via the usual \label and \ref commands, using someprefix- to distinguish between the labels in file-1.tex and those in file-2.tex.

I am wondering what the syntax should be if file-2.tex is in folder-2 instead of folder-1. I have already tried:

```
\externaldocument[someprefix-]{../file-2}
\externaldocument[someprefix-]{~/...insert-relevant-directory-here.../folder-2/file-2}
```

but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd expect `../folder2/file-2` to work, `~` would also work if you use `\string~/...` to prevent `~` expanding to non-breakable space

Comment: "nothing works" isn't a description that anyone can debug. If it gives the wrong output, show the output, if it gives an error message or warning, show the text from the log file.

Comment: have you tried the `subfile` package already? This also allows you to compile parts separate from each other while writing and all together for the finish.

Comment: @David Carlisle: yes, you're right. What happens is that the file compiles (there is syntaxically nothing wrong of course) but the references appear as wrong (i.e. as ?? instead of 3.7 or something). I know that the error must be there however, since the same file-2.tex is in both folders, and when I change that \externaldocument line to work within folder-1 (i.e. if I write "file-2" as an argument instead like in my first example), everything works fine.

Comment: You need the same path that you would need to input the file. So *if you compile in folder-1* `../folder-2/file-2` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the time guys. Turns out I was a bit tired when working long hours and I wrote "Commutative-Algebra" with three m's somewhere. I did mess up the references a few times before getting it right though, so the confidence given by your comments was indeed useful!...         

Speaking of which, how would I go and replace that "folder-1" name by a "folder 1"? I tried using "folder\ 1" (as I would in my terminal when using the cd command in Linux for instance) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
\externaldocument[someprefix-]{../folder-2/file-2}
```

Notice: Do not include the .tex extension.